Is there a way of customising days in two letters instead of one in month view in Full Calendar?
i am trying to customise the days in the header in resourceTimelineMonth but could not find a suitable way of doing it.
I would like to show it like 1Tu 2We 3Th instead of 1T 2W 3T
I am using V6 and i see that in previous version it is a default behaviour. 
<FullCalendar
titleFormat={customTitleFormat}
/>

    const customTitleFormat = ({ date }) => {
        if (!date) {
            return "";
        }
        const dayNumber = date?.getDate(); // Get the day of the month
        const dayNames = ["SU", "MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR", "SA"]; // Short day names
        const dayIndex = date?.getDay(); // Get the index of the day (0-6)
        const dayAbbreviation = dayNames[dayIndex]; // Get the corresponding short name
        return `${dayNumber}${dayAbbreviation}`; // Return formatted string
    };

